# I Have been trying to access data in json file using node js but getting the output as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
var fs =require('fs');

var contents=fs.readFileSync('./emailsender.json');

var jsoncontent=JSON.parse(contents);

console.log(jsoncontent["to"]);
```

emailsender.json

```
[{"to":"kshitiz@zillion.io","from":"kshitiz@zillion.io"},{"to":"kshitiz.orizion@gmail.com","from":"kshitiz.orizion@gmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(jsoncontent[0].to)`

`jsoncontent` is an array of objects.